# Is there local minimums in MSE function?

Tags: gradient-descent, calculus

Here is "mean squared error" function: C = $\frac{1}{2n}$ * $\sum(length(y - a)^2)$

As I understand, this is like paraboloid in multidimensional space. So, I guess, there is only one extremum: global mimum. But subconsciously I'm not 100% sure of it. Can you explain whether I'm right or wrong?

Comment: It is a convex function, and so any minimum is a global minimum.

Comment: @AnnaSdTC, why do not you write a normal answer?

Comment: What is a normal answer? You asked if there is a global minimum, I say yes, any minimum is a global minimum.

Comment: > You asked if there is a global minimum;;;

I asked: Is there LOCAL MINIMUMS in MSE function?;;;

> any minimum is a global minimum;;;

"any" means that there any multiple minimums, but there are SINGLE minimum

Comment: No, it means that, if you find a minimum (i.e., a point with lower value of the function than any point in its neighborhood), then it is a global minimum. It also means that any point for which all the partial derivatives are zero is a global minimum.

Comment: What is "length" in the equation? What is "a"? Is it a function of something, or is it a constant?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the $(y - x)^2$ is convex in $x$ does not mean that $(y - f(x))^2$ is convex in $x$ in general. See [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11979/how-is-it-possible-that-the-mse-used-to-train-neural-networks-with-gradient-desc) on AISE. So yes, you can have local minima that are not global minima.

Comment: True -- but this mischaracterizes the question, which concerns the minimum of $f(x,y)^2.$ The distinction matters, because since there are at most two points where the function $g(z)=z^2$ is minimized (depending on its domain), we can characterize the minima of $f(x,y)^2 = g(f(x,y))$ as the inverse images of those one or two points under $f.$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. MSE(Mean Square Error) could only have a convex plane which bent only downward. So, There couldn't exist local minima.